# /:$foovar/ What does this do in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking at a Perl script to figure what it does.

I came across this

```
if (/:$array[k]/)
```

What does `/:$something/` do in Perl?

Comment: See "Quote and Quote-like Operators" in "man perlop" (Perl Operators). Maybe also have a look at [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) (which I remembered as *fine*, BTW).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a regular expression, [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), matching against `$_`.
Specifically the `$` is not treated as a regex special character here, but starts *expression evaluation* instead (the expression is `$array[k]`.
So it matches `:` followed by whatever is in `$array[k]`. `$array[k]` looks wrong though. It should probably be `$array[$k]`.

Example:

```perl
#!/bin/perl

my @array=qw(foo bar baz);

$_ = 'XXX:barXXX';
my $k = 1;

if (/:$array[$k]/) {  # :$array[$k] is ":bar"
    print "Match\n";  # prints Match because :bar is found in $_
}
```

Note: If the elements in `array` are *not* supposed to be interpreted as `regex` patterns as they would in your original example, you'll need to quote the interpolation of `$array[$k]` with `\Q`...`\E`:

```perl
if (/:\Q$array[$k]\E/)
```

`\E` can be left out in the above example since we want everything after `\Q` to be matching literally.

Comment: The actual value was 4 not k. I generalized it to k in an informed manner.

Comment: Wouldn't `$array[k]` substitute the value of `$array`, followed by the literal string "[k]", or would it raise a warning?

Answer (score 0):

Perl's regular expressions are a double-quoted context. This means it will interpolate the same sequences any other double-quoted context before it constructs the pattern. Whatever is in `$array[$k]` is now part of the pattern, and any special meta-characters are still special.